# Use jupyter nbconvert to run pyspark job on standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, jupyter

I've ever used **jupyter notebook** to run on pyspark standalone mode.

It just need to set:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook ..."
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
```

AND run

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/pyspark --master spark://ip:7077
```

We really like to use Jupyter as our production solution, and think **jupyter nbconvert** is an excellent command for us to do some scheduling or daily batch job.

Currently, we still cannot find a way to use **jupyter nbconvert** to run pyspark standalone. Hope someone can kindly provide experience about this.

Great thanks!

Comment: What is the error you encounter here?